# Coloring an undirected graph with prob. distribution of neighbour pairs?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, graph-theory

Let's say we have an undirected graph, and we want to color each vertex one of N colors.

We want the colors picked randomly, but biased, such that for each pair of neighbouring vertices, the probability that they have a pair of specific vertex colors is given by a symmetric probability matrix.  ie The matrix is NxN and each row (and column) adds up to 1.  Color i corresponds to row (and column) i.

If we are picking the color for a vertex that has exactly one neighbour that is already colored, it is easy:  We just use the corresponding row for the neighbours color as a probability distribution.

But what if two (or more) of the neighbours are already colored?  How do we derive the probability distribution from the matrix?

Also how do we pick the color of a vertex that does not yet have any colored neighbours?  How do we derive the "initial" distribution from the matrix?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A simple event in your problem is not coloring a single vertex, but coloring the whole graph. Each simple event has its own probability, and these probabilities sum up to $1$. When you color a single vertex you choose a subset of simple events and thier probabilities are scaled up to sum up to $1$. Note that now your matrix of each edge changes, no matter is it incident to the coloured vertex or not.

Let consider an example. Suppose you have $3$ vertices and $2$ colors. Each coloring is a $3$-digit binary number and I select some meaningless probabilities:
$$p_{000} = 1 / 87, p_{001} = 2 / 87, p_{010} = 3 / 87, p_{011} = 5 / 87,\\p_{100} = 8 / 87, p_{101} = 13 / 87, p_{110} = 21 / 87, p_{111} = 34 / 87.$$

It actually doesn't matter whether your graph has certain edge or not, there is some matrix of probabilities for any pair of vertices. In our case we have $3$ pairs and $3$ matrices:

$$\begin{bmatrix}3/87 & 8/87\\ 21/87 & 55/87\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}4/87 & 7/87\\ 29/87 & 47/87\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}9/87 & 15/87\\ 24/87 & 39/87\end{bmatrix}.$$

But if you select the color $0$ for the first vertex, then the matrix for the second and the third vertices instantly changes from $\begin{bmatrix}9/87 & 15/87\\ 24/87 & 39/87\end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix}1/11 & 2/11\\ 3/11 & 5/11\end{bmatrix}$.

So you need to think about the probabilities of simple events. If you can investigate structure of your problem you should focus on finding these probabilities. If your matrices are all you are given and you need to model such coloring then you may imagine some probabilities of simple events, giving you the desired matrices. And then you are free to model colors of vertices one by one scaling probabilities of the remaining simple events.

It's up to you how to imagine the probabilities of simple events. Essentially you have $n^N$ variables and $mN^2$ linear equations, where $n$ is the number of vertices and $m$ is the number of edges. For $N \ge 2$ and big enough $n$ you will have plenty of free variables in this system of equations. You may nullify (or ignore) them, or give some groups of them other values, just care about you system to have at least one solution. Once you have a solution start modelling coloring.

In our example given three matrices you could let $p_{000} = 0$, then you would get
$$p_{000} = 0, p_{001} = 3/87, p_{010} = 4/87, p_{011} = 4/87,\\p_{100} = 9/87, p_{101} = 12/87, p_{110} = 20/87, p_{111} = 35/87.$$